# How to recreate a UIView for a UITableViewCell's contentView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have created a `UITableView` that has many static `UITableViewCell`s. I've changed the style of just one of these static cells to Custom. I've created an outlet for this cell so that I may programmatically add subviews to its `contentView`. In `viewWillAppear` I create a `UILabel` and configure it appropriately. I then test against some condition, and if it's true I create a `UIView` and add the `UILabel` as a subview to it, then I add that `UIView` to the cell's `contentView`.  If it's not true, I just add the `UILabel` itself to the `contentView`.

This works great when the cell appears for the first time, but if I perform a push segue then navigate back, the `contentView` isn't reset so it appears the same as it did when it first appeared. It should have changed because the condition checked against has changed. I knew this was because it simply added another subview. So I cleverly added a `tag` to the `UIView` or `UILabel` when it was created, then before I run the code to create the appropriate view I remove the view with that `tag` from the superview. I also store a reference to the `UILabel` (not the `UIView`), so I set that to `nil` afterwards as well.

The end result is the cell appears just fine the first time it is rendered, but after returning to it from a push segue, the subview is removed as expected but another subview is not added so the cell is completely empty. I stepped through the code and it's all called so I'm not sure why nothing appears after removing it the first time.

EDIT: This must be an issue with the autoresizingMask - setting the frame manually works. How could I ensure the frames always fill the parent frame?

```
//Store reference to UILabel and bool to test again
var label: UILabel?
var someCondition = false

//viewWillAppear:
cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100)?.removeFromSuperview()
label = nil

//This is the issue - frame is always size 1,1
//label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 70, 20))
label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1))
label!.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight

label!.text = "testing"
label!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

someCondition = !someCondition
if someCondition == true {
    var view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    //need to replace static frame with autoresizingMask here too
    view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 70)
    view.tag = 100
    view.addSubview(label!)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
} else{
    label!.tag = 100
    cell.contentView.addSubview(label!)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce you problem with code similar to yours. I tested it with the code below. I have an unwind segue in the detail controller that calls cameBackFromDetail, which, as you can see, just negates the value of the Bool. When I go back and forth, I see the cell alternate between a cell with view with a label, or just the label. On the other hand, if I go back using the back button, I see the same cell as when I left, as I should.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell: UITableViewCell!
    var label: UILabel?
    var someCondition: Bool = false

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let aView = cell.viewWithTag(100) {
            aView.removeFromSuperview()
            label = nil
        }
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 70, 20))
        label!.text = "testing"
        label!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        if someCondition == true {
            var view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 70)
            view.tag = 100
            view.addSubview(label!)
            cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
        }else{
            label!.tag = 100
            cell.contentView.addSubview(label!)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func cameBackFromDetail(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        someCondition = !someCondition
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying this! I've found the issue, it's not related to adding/removing the view or label. The problem is instead of setting the frame to a fixed size, I use an auto resizing mask, and that's not working properly - not sure why. I will edit the question with code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Joey, yeah, I noticed that too, which is why I don't have that line in my code.

Comment: Dang, I need that frame to adjust to always fill the parent. I thought this would work, odd. How would I achieve that?

Comment: @Joey, use layout constraints

Comment: Thanks that will work, just a pain. :) Do you believe this is a bug with the `autoresizingMask`? It should have worked, right?

Comment: @Joey, I'm not sure. I've been using layout constraints for so long now, that I don't remember how autoresizing works.